# Finding distribution and density function of $X^2/(X^2+Y^2)$ where $X,Y∼N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, convolution, density-function

I have two random independent standard normal variables $X,Y∼N(0,1)$.

How can I find the distribution of $\,\dfrac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2}\;?$

I know that if we talk about only $X^2$ then it will be a Chi-Square distribution.

Comment: You can try the following: $(X,Y) / \|(X,Y)\|$ follows the uniform distribution on the unit circle, which has a density on this circle; if $T$ is the first coordinate of this distribution, then you are after the density of $T^2.$

Comment: Agree with first comment!  Also, by symmetry $Z=\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2}$ has same distribution as $1-\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2}=\frac{Y^2}{X^2+Y^2}$, so the distribution $Z$ is supported on $[0,1]$ and is symmetric about $z=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try my best to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2}\leq a\right)&=\Pr\left(\frac{Y^2}{X^2}\geq \frac{1-a}{a}\right)\\
&=1-\Pr\left(\frac{Y^2}{X^2}\leq \frac{1-a}{a}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{\int_0^{1-a}t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}dt}{B(1/2,1/2)}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{1-a}t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}dt
\end{align}

Note: $Y^2/X^2$ is Fisher with $(1,1)$ degrees of freedom and its CDF you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution). Also from the comments you see that $0\leq a\leq1$.

Furher, the pdf turns out to be $$f(a)=\frac{1}{\pi}(1-a)^{-1/2}a^{-1/2},$$ so the quantity you are analyzing is a $\beta(1/2,1/2)$ variate.

Comment: Hi! What happened in the upper limit of integration, third line? Shouldn't the integral be from $0$ to $(1-a)/a$ ?

Comment: the upper limit should be $\frac{1\times \frac{1-a}{a}}{1\times \frac{1-a}{a} +1}$ where the 1's are the degrees of freedom, see this link for details:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution